# grafana alert delete rules with file provisioning

Tags: yaml, google-kubernetes-engine, grafana, grafana-alerts, grafana-templating

I am trying to delete the alerts from my GKE cluster which is deployed with a file provisioning template. below is my yaml to delete multiple alerts at a time with respective UID's. But I get " error: X failure to parse file provider. yaml : yaml: unmarshal errors:". Any suggestions on how to delete multiple uids? or even delete the alert folder? If I provide the uid as below it works

Working yaml:

```
  provider.yaml: |-
    apiVersion: 1
    deleteRules:
      - orgsId: 1
        uid: hssksks222
```

But when I provide the yaml as below it gives the error: X failure to parse file provider.yaml : yaml: unmarshal errors:"
Non working yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  labels:
    helm.sh/chart: grafana-6.9.0
    app.kubernetes.io/name: grafana
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: pro-grafana
    app.kubernetes.io/version: "7.5."
  name: grafana-alerting
  namespace: grafana-monitoring
data:
  provider.yaml: |-
    apiVersion: 1
    deleteRules:
      - orgsId: 1
        uid:
          - hssksks222
          - gjdjdu244ss
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for me.

```
  deleteRules:
    - orgId: 1
      uid: hssksks222
    - orgId: 1
      uid: gjdjdu244ss
```